# Python. Пожалуйста помогите понять в чём ошибка

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Задание в котором есть файл с данными о студентах которые прошли тест, нужно добавить столбец в котором будет число полученное делением потраченного времени на на сумму балов за ответы на вопросы и отсортировать от самого большого числа к самому низкому.

Для этого задания решил воспользоваться pandas.

Код который написал ->

```
import pandas as pd

    with open('marks.csv', "r+") as file:
        data = file.read()
    
    with open('marks_new.csv', "wt+") as file:
        file.seek(0)
        file.write('ПІБ, початок часу, кінець часу, затрачений час, Питання 1, Питання 2, Питання 3, Питання 4, Питання 6, Питання 6, Питання 7, Питання 8, Питання 9, Питання 10, Питання 11, Питання 12, Питання 13, Питання 14, Питання 15, Питання 16, Питання 17, Питання 18, Питання 19, Питання 20, Питання 21\n' + data)
    
    students_df = pd.read_csv('marks_new.csv')
    
    students_df['оцінка\час'] = (students_df['Питання 1'] + students_df['Питання 2'] + students_df['Питання 3'] + students_df['Питання 4'] + students_df['Питання 5'] + students_df['Питання 6'] + students_df['Питання 7'] + students_df['Питання 8'] + students_df['Питання 9'] + students_df['Питання 10'] + students_df['Питання 11'] + students_df['Питання 12'] + students_df['Питання 13'] + students_df['Питання 14'] + students_df['Питання 15'] + students_df['Питання 16'] + students_df['Питання 18'] + students_df['Питання 19'] + students_df['Питання 20'] + students_df['Питання 21']) / students_df['затрачений час']
    
    print(students_df)
```

В итоге даже не дошёл до сортировки, выдаёт ошибку на строке

> students_df['оцінка\час'].....

Ошибка под названием

> Питання 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет в питоне такой ошибки. Приведите в вопросе весь текст ошибки, а не свою интерпретацию.

Comment: Я понимаю что такой ошибки по идеи нету, но мне её выбивает(добавил скриншот), по этому и не могу понять и в чём ошибка и почему именно так выбивает ошибку

Comment: А вот нажмите там "Показать стек вызовов" и нам покажите, что там

Comment: Я вот не вижу открывающую скобку в строке `students_df['оцінка\час'] = ...`, а только закрывающую

Comment: Стек вызовов добавил, а на счёт скобки это я случайно удалил одну, когда вставлял в текст(сейчас исправлю)

Comment: Нда, тоже не очень информативно. А напечатайте для начала `print(students_df.columns)`, есть ли нужные колонки там вообще?

Comment: То что вывело сделал скрин и добавил к теме сверху

Comment: Добавьте лучше текстом. Нужно сравнить символы, может где-то ошибка. А, так у вас пробел лишний в названиях почти всех столбцов в самом датафрейме.

Comment: Не увидел что есть пробелы, по убирал их и всё относительно заработало, в плане появилась другая ошибка(на этот раз нормальная). "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'", я так понимаю проблема в том что у меня типа делиться строка на строку, только насколько я знаю в pandas если числа содержаться отдельно в строке, то их должно преобразовывать в нужный тип....

Comment: В итоге вроде конвертировал таким способом  "pd.to_numeric(students_df['Питання 21'], errors='coerce')", но выводит по итогу NAN, не понимаю в чём прикол....

Comment: В любом случае ошибка данной темы исправлена, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ну видимо где-то не может преобразовать в число. Например, разделитель перед дробной частью может быть не тот, например, у вас запятая, а ожидается точка. Короче, это нужно данные смотреть.

Comment: Как раз додумал до того что вы написали и действительно надо поменять "," на ".", но в итоге выдё'т ошибку типа нельзя преобразовать в другой тип потому что есть такая строка "0,             8.00", собственно такой строки в файле в помине нету и я подумал что может каким то образом она захватывает строку с названием столбцов и написал такую строку "students_df['оцінка\час'] = pd.to_numeric(re.findall(r'\d+\.\d*|\.\d+', str(students_df['Питання 1']).replace(',', '.')))", и в итоге начало выдовать ошибку "Length of values (171) does not match length of index (170)"

Comment: Пожалуйста, еще один раз: Не фото, а **текст** программы, ошибок и всего остального, чтобы возможно было копировать через буфер для тех, которые вам хотят помочь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('marks.lab6.csv', "r+") as file:
data = file.read()

with open('marks_new.csv', "wt+") as file:
    file.seek(0)
    file.write('ПІБ,початок часу,кінець часу,затрачений час,Питання 1,Питання 2,Питання 3,Питання 4,Питання 5,Питання 6,Питання 7,Питання 8,Питання 9,Питання 10,Питання 11,Питання 12,Питання 13,Питання 14,Питання 15,Питання 16,Питання 17,Питання 18,Питання 19,Питання 20,Питання 21\n' + data)



pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

students_df = pd.read_csv('marks_new.csv')

students_df['Питання 1'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 1']]
students_df['Питання 2'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 2']]
students_df['Питання 3'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 3']]
students_df['Питання 4'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 4']]
students_df['Питання 5'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 5']]
students_df['Питання 6'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 6']]
students_df['Питання 7'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 7']]
students_df['Питання 8'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 8']]
students_df['Питання 9'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 9']]
students_df['Питання 10'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 10']]
students_df['Питання 11'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 11']]
students_df['Питання 12'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 12']]
students_df['Питання 13'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 13']]
students_df['Питання 14'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 14']]
students_df['Питання 15'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 15']]
students_df['Питання 16'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 16']]
students_df['Питання 17'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 17']]
students_df['Питання 18'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 18']]
students_df['Питання 19'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 19']]
students_df['Питання 20'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 20']]
students_df['Питання 21'] = [x.replace(',', '.').replace('-', '0') for x in students_df['Питання 21']]

students_df['затрачений час'] = [x.replace('хв', '').replace('сек', '') for x in students_df['затрачений час']]
students_df['затрачений час'] = [x.split(" ")[0] for x in students_df['затрачений час']]

students_df['оцінка\час'] = (students_df['Питання 1'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 2'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 3'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 4'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 5'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 6'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 7'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 8'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 9'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 10'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 11'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 12'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 13'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 14'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 15'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 16'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 17'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 18'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 19'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 20'].astype(float) + students_df['Питання 21'].astype(float)) / students_df['затрачений час'].astype(float)

students_df = students_df.sort_values('оцінка\час')
students_df.reset_index(drop= True , inplace= True )

students_df.head().to_csv("Answer.txt", mode="a+", header=False, sep='|')
```

Программа исправлена и дописана, огромная благодарность CrazyElf

Comment: Хм, уважаемый CrazyElf дал вам правильное направление. А вот реализация..... А что произойдет, если в вашей базе появиться ще одне питання??? Вы будете скрипт переписывать? В него операторы добавалять? Жах! Я в таких случаях говорю, что для любителей вот так кодить следующий раз в задании будет 973 "питань", и я посмотрю на ваш скрипт и как вы его будете писать. Если уж решили обнародовать ваш ответ, то хоть напишите его по-человечески, что бы оно было достойно этого ресурса.